# how to add 'host_name' extension for SNI in java (using jetty)

Tags: java, ssl, jetty

i am trying in every way to add the SNI to my client (jetty 11.0.9). The server requires me to send host_name, but there is no way with jetty. can anyone do it?

Answer (score 0):

Jetty's `HttpClient` uses the Java `SSLEngine` to initiate TLS connections and will use SNI by default.

Just use one of the `HttpClient.newRequest()` methods to create a Request with either an absolute URI (that includes the authority, hostname, port) or the `newRequest()` methods that take a hostname / port pair.

Note that the Java SSLEngine will follow the TLS/SNI spec and *will not send SNI* if the destination host is `localhost` or an IP Address (you must use a hostname, always, with SNI)